# how to exclude posts on current page from recent posts sidebar widget

Tags: sidebar

I am using Wordpress 3.6. I would like to exclude posts on any given current page from appearing in the recent posts sidebar widget. I haven't been able to find a custom widget that has that option. I hope someone can help.

Comment: The built-in (WordPress Core) recent posts widget?

Comment: Yes, the built-in recent posts widget as it's fine the way it is. I just want to exclude posts from a current page from it.

Comment: You can use the `'widget_posts_args'` WordPress filter to add an [array of excluded posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) to the widget query.

Comment: Thanks for responding but I didn't find anything that excludes a page, current or otherwise. Can anyone tell me what I'd need to put to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the functions.php theme (or child theme) file.

```
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'wpse_109484_recent_post_count' );

function wpse_109484_recent_post_count( $args ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $excluded_posts = array();
    foreach ( (array) $wp_query->posts as $post ) {
        $excluded_posts[] = $post->ID;
    }

    $args['post__not_in'] = $excluded_posts;

    return $args;
}
```